# using index.html(mainstream webpage, not a popup.html) how to send data from content.js to background.js only after onClick method?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

The whole point is to send some data from HTML page(Not a popup window) to content.js page when fired a **onclick** and then send it to background.js file to perform some function with the data but i'm facing some errors to get it.

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" id='fullname' />
<button onclick="sendData()">Submit</button>
```

**Content.js**

chrome.runtime.sendMessage() method works fine when inside document.onLoad() but having an issue calling it inside a normal function

```
function sendData(){
    var fullName = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "message": fullName }
    ,(res)=>console.log(res))
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);

function receiver(data, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (data.message !== undefined) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse(`${data.message} is submitted as your fullname`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Extensions do not allow you to have inline JavaScript ([documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)).

Instead, assign an id to your button with `<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>` and use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to bind the `sendData()` function as an event.

**Content.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    button.addEventListener('click', sendData);
});

function sendData() {
    const fullName = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "message": fullName }, (response) => console.log(response))
}
```